# Invoking an interactive ssh shell in python

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko, netcat

Im trying to gain an interactive shell via paramiko, I understand executing single commands via `client.invoke_shell()` and then sending a string on that channel, BUT im looking for a way to get a shell and stay on it, my purpose for this specifically is to launch a python script to get a netcat listener on my server and keep the shell session open so I can interact with the callback.

Comment: try [tag:expect] or [tag:pexpect]